# calling a vb.net class from c# in VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-to-vb.net

So i am working on a wpf browser project in c# but on of the class library's I need is in vb.net.  So in VS2010 I have imported the solution called vblib and it shows up on the solution explorer.  The class i need is public class vbintopm.  So right now I have

`using vblib;`

```
       //down a few lines
vbintopm callvb= new vbintopm;
```

>
now I keep getting errors that VS can't find class even though its in the solution explorer.  What do i need to fix to this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to actually *reference* the library from your C# project. Right-click the project and then select "Add Reference". On the "Projects" tab, select the project and click "OK".

Comment: As its a DLL (Class Library), "Add reference" then click on the "Browse" tab and locate the DLL.

Comment: @Jason: That also works, except if he has the project in the same solution, then adding a project reference makes sure Visual Studio always builds them in the correct order (though you could also do that with an explicit dependency, but lets not get too complicated ;)